# close parent window on load of child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, parent-child

I have a pop up window which has a button. `onclick` of the button I open another window using `window.open(url)`. I want to close the parent window in `onload` event of the child event.

I tried `window.opener.close()`. But it was not of any help.
I open the child window using the following code in the parent window

```
$(function () {
    $('#testpopup').click(function () {
         window.open('complete.aspx');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
parent.window.opener.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ttry this

```
var w = window.opener;
    window.opener = self;
    w.close();
```

Comment: Do I need to place this in the child window?

Comment: It didnt work. Is it because i dont open the parent window using javascript or ' window.open()' ?

Comment: oh sorry i know this only